# Force constant dimensions of a HTML video element regardless of dimensions and ratio of source

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I am trying to do a not so simple task. I would like to have in a HTML5 page a video element with constant width and height (those of the window), that can manages the dimensions and aspect ratio of the source video to display at best that is to say with the window fully covered with the video and with no scroll bars.

I wrote this javascript code:

```
 $("video").bind("loadedmetadata", function () {
      var screenSize = {}, videoSize = {};
      videoSize["width"] = this.videoWidth;
      videoSize["height"] = this.videoHeight;
      screenSize["height"] = $( window ).height();
      screenSize["width"] = $( window ).width();

      var ratio_screen = screenSize["width"]/screenSize["height"];
      var ratio_video = videoSize["width"]/videoSize["height"];

        if (ratio_video > ratio_screen) {
          $("video").height(screenSize["height"]);
          $("video").width(screenSize["height"]*ratio_screen);
        } 
        else 
          {
          $("video").width(screenSize["width"]);
          $("video").height(screenSize["width"]/ratio_screen);
            }

        });
```

At the moment, I have a video element, almost fitting the window (I still have a border or margin that inspector says to be part of html element). But the source video is fitting inside the video element! As an example for my test video which is wider than the screen, I have a black strip over and under the video.

How can I manage this to "zoom" the video. Do I have to apply a scaling factor to the video element or somenthing can be done at source video level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally this piece of code worked:

```
$("video").on('canplay',function() {
  $("video").bind("loadedmetadata", function () {
      var screenSize = {}, videoSize = {};

      videoSize["width"] = this.videoWidth;
      videoSize["height"] = this.videoHeight;
      screenSize["height"] = $( window ).height();
      screenSize["width"] = $( window ).width();

      var ratio_screen = screenSize["width"]/screenSize["height"];
      var ratio_video = videoSize["width"]/videoSize["height"];

      if (ratio_video > ratio_screen) {
        $("video").css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+ratio_video/ratio_screen+")");
        $("video").height(screenSize["height"]);
        $("video").width(screenSize["height"]*ratio_screen);
      } else {
        $("video").css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+ratio_video/ratio_screen+")");
        $("video").width(screenSize["width"]);
        $("video").height(screenSize["width"]/ratio_screen);
      }
  });
});
```

This results in displaying a video, filling the whole screen, without stretching the video if the aspect ratio is not fitting the one of the screen.
Note that my video element plays several sources in a loop. The first video played does not apply this resizing function (I have to work on that to ensure the at start up this works).